# Erro ao ligar a BD postgres com PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

Tenho o Postgres 9.3 instalado num servidor Windows server 2012. Preciso recolher informação da BD para consulta num site. Já configurei o router da rede encaminhando a porta 5432.

No pg_hba alterei a linha: `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

No postgresql coloquei a linha: `listen_addresses = '*'`

Num pc remoto consigo ligar o pgAdminIII à base de dados.

No site, utilizando php tentei ligar utilizando:

```
$liga = "host=xxxxx.no-ip.net port=5432 dbname=gwrcsg01f1 user=postgres password=xxxxxxx";

$conn = pg_connect($liga) or die('Falha de ligacao ao servidor');

$result = pg_query($conn , "SELECT * FROM clientes;");

$registo = pg_fetch_array($result);

pg_close();
```

Recebo sempre 'Falha de ligação ao servidor'. Se ligar a uma BD local do site funciona. Não sei se é relevante mas no site está o php 5.4 e tentei também o 5.6.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Pelo pc remoto você se conecta usando esse endereço `host=xxxxx.no-ip.net port=5432` ?

Comment: Sim. utilizo os mesmos dados

Answer (score 2):

Já consegui descobrir. Fica aqui para quem venha a ter problemas idênticos.
O servidor do alojamento estava a bloquear a saída. Tive que solicitar que me autorizassem a ligação.